# How to force hiding the keyboard in Ubuntu Touch

Tags: keyboard, ubuntu-touch

First of all, I want to give you an example to describe you the problem: All the time I want to use the Voicemessage option from Markcortbass' App 'WebWhatsapp', the OnScreen keyboard appears on the screen and I can't record. In this case Ubuntu Touch seems to recognize the text field on the left side and switches into the typing mode. To avoid this, I must connect a physical keyboard to my device. That's annoying. That might not be a bug from Markcortbass because the code of the Whatsapp Web is owned by Whatsapp itself and not manipulatable. However, now to my general question: Is there a way to temporaryly disable the OnScreen keyboard when there's no physical keyboard connected? E.g. a launcher or a small app running in background and suppressing the OnScreen keyboard? Thanks in advice!

Comment: Is dragging the on-screen keyboard down the screen not useful?

Comment: No, sorry. It comes again and again. :(

Answer (score 0):

Bjarne, I found [this bug description](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity8/+bug/1518423), where [Michael Zanetti suggests](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity8/+bug/1518423/comments/1) this command for analyzing of one situation:

```
gsettings get com.canonical.keyboard.maliit stay-hidden
```

so, I think this should work:

```
gsettings set com.canonical.keyboard.maliit stay-hidden true
```

Comment: Very nice, thanks! I should create a launcher for switching this property.

Comment: I've tested this method from ssh terminal, it works for me. Do you know how to do such launcher?

Comment: I already created one toggling between true and false. It's primitive, but it's working.

Answer (score 0):

Create a bash file and paste this:

```
#!/bin/bash

SCHEMA="com.canonical.keyboard.maliit"
KEY="stay-hidden"

STATUS=$(gsettings get ${SCHEMA} ${KEY})

if [ ${STATUS} == true ]; then
    gsettings set ${SCHEMA} ${KEY} false
else
    gsettings set ${SCHEMA} ${KEY} true
fi
```

Important: Make the bash file executable (chmod +x)!
Then create a launcher (.desktop file) in ~/.local/share/applications and paste this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=OnScreen Keyboard Toggle
Type=Application
Terminal=false
X-Ubuntu-Touch=true
Icon=keyboard
Exec=PATH_OF_THE_BASH_FILE
```

The launcher appears on the App scope of your Ubuntu Touch Device. When you tab on it, it opens for a few seconds and gets closed. In this time the maliit keyboard has been toggled. Tab again to toggle back.